# Live search suggestions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, livesearch

I used ajax to create a live search connected to the database(site e-commerce). when there is a value in the input several suggestions are fetched in the screen . I want to take the id when the client click in a suggestion. The suggestions cant be clickable i dont know why!! here is my jquery code :

```
    $('.clicked').click(function() {
        console.log($("#input_value").val());
        
    });

    var x;
    var value = $("#input_value").val();
    $('.clicked').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
    //     // url: 'test.php?name=' + $("#testo").val(),
        data: { name : value },
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function()
        {
            window.location.href = 'un_produit.php?id=' + $("#input_value").val();
        
        }
    });
```

I tried to add the class to a div and it works when i click but it doesnt work with the suggestions of the live search .

Comment: Hard to be sure precisely what's going on without seeing relevant html, or how your search works (always provide a [mre] of the issue please), but probably the suggestions didn't exist when you bound the click event. Learn about delegated event handling...jquery makes it fairly easy.

Comment: It's hard to tell without all the relevant code, but at least one thing is wrong at the first look: this line `var value = $("#input_value").val();` should be inside the `click` handler function, or else it takes the value once, when the handlers are set, and never updates so it will not take in account what the user enters in the input. But you doesn't seem to do anything with the value anyways and you do nothing with the AJAX result so that's hard to tell. Doing an AJAX request to make a redirection seems a weird practice too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, I had to add the `class="clicked"` into the the child element of the suggestion div and not to the div itself. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using an `AJAX` request you could use `JQUERY` autocomplete.
This is an easy example on how this works, your URL source should return the data in this format:

```
 [{"label": "item 1", "value": "0"}, {"label": "item 2", "value": "2"}, {"label": "item 3", "value": "3"}]
```

I used this url as reference: https://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/

```js
$(function() {
        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: [{"label": "item 1", "value": "0"}, {"label": "item 2", "value": "2"}, {"label": "item 3", "value": "3"}], // this can be an url as well
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var label = ui.item.label;
                if (label === "no results") {
                    // this prevents "no results" from being selected
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                else {

                    /* do something with the selected result */
                    $("#autocomplete").val(ui.item.label);
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // or get the id
                     $("#autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);

                }

            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="autocomplete">
```

Comment: 1. Autocomplete is still using AJAX, as the OP needs to get the data from their server-side endpoint. 2. jQueryUI is very outdated, I'd not recommend its use any longer.